# Customizing the suggestions in Android keyboard

Tags: android

Android keyboard shows suggestions while typing in it. The values are picked from the contacts. I am writing an application in which the values suggested from contacts do not make scene e.g. names of different operating systems (these names will not be in contact list).

I want to customize this suggestions so that Android keyboard displays the suggestions from the list of values given by me.

Comment: Displaying your own suggestions might not even be possible with all the keyboards out there. So I'd suggest that you disable suggestions completely and look into autocomplete for your editText.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though it would be better to create a list of operating systems and allow the user to choose between them. Look at ListFragments [(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html))